# Grid of Refs in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-ref

I am trying make a grid in React typescript, want to access the nodes with refs inside each node I am using the useImperativeHandle to return a fucntion and nodeState

```
const Grid: React.FC<PropsType> = (props) => {
    const makeGrid = (): void => {
        const newGrid: gridNode[][] = []
        for (let i = 0; i < HIEGHT; i++) {
            const gridRow: gridNode[] = []
            for (let j = 0; j < WIDTH; j++) {
                const node: gridNode = {
                    row: i,
                    col: j,
                    ref: React.createRef<NodeHandle>()
                }
                gridRow.push(node)
            }
            newGrid.push(gridRow)
        }
        setGrid(newGrid)
    }

    useEffect(() => { makeGrid() }, [])
    
    return (
         <>
            {grid.forEach(row => {
                 return (<>
                      {row.forEach(node => {
                          <Node ref = {node.ref} />
                       })
                 </>)
            })
         </>
    )
}
```

I want to use `useRef()` hook to make it more inline with the fucntional components I am using, and I don't know if its best practice to put the refs in the state object

```
const Node: React.ForwardRefRenderFunction<NodeHandle, NodeProps> = (props, ref) => {
       
        changeStatus = (newStatus: string) => {
             //changes the status
        }
        useImperativeHandle(ref, () => {
            return {
               changeStatus,
               status,
        }
    })
    return (
      <div>Node</div>
    )
}
```

I am very new to typeScript, also haven't previously worked this much with refs

Answer (score 1):

`forEach()` doesn't return anything.  You need to use `.map()` instead when you are looping through nodes.

`React.ForwardRefRenderFunction` is not the right type for the `Node` component.  That's the type that describes the inner function *inside* of `forwardRef`.  But you aren't actually calling `forwardRef` anywhere.  You want:

```
const Node = forwardRef<NodeHandle, NodeProps>((props, ref) => {
```

---

`useImperativeHandle` is generally not necessary. It's better to lift state up to the parent instead.

It seems like the information which you are getting from each node is its `status` and a callback to change that status.  You can move the status state up into the `Grid` component and pass those two values down to the `Node` as props instead.

I can see why the ref-based approach looks appealing compared to making updates in a 2D array.  So maybe rethink the shape of your state to something flatter?

```
const Node = ({status, changeStatus}: NodeProps) => {
    return (
        <div>Node</div>
    )
};

const Grid: React.FC<PropsType> = (props) => {

    const initialStatus = "initial";

    /**
     * Store a partial object of node statuses keyed by the key for each node.
     * Formulate each key as "row-column".
     * Assume that any key which isn't present has the initial value.
     * This allows you to avoid creating an object of initial states.
     */
    const [keyedStatuses, setKeyedStatuses] = useState<Partial<Record<string, string>>>({});

    /**
     * Iterate through all row indexes and column indexes.
     * The arrays are filled with `undefined`, so 
     * skip the value and just use the index.
     */
    return (
        <>
            {Array.from({length: HEIGHT}).map((_, i) =>
                Array.from({length: WIDTH}).map((_, j) => {
                    const key = `${i}-${j}`;
                    return (
                        <Node
                            key={key}
                            // get the current status
                            status={keyedStatuses[key] ?? initialStatus}
                            // update the status for just this node
                            changeStatus={(newStatus: string) => setKeyedStatuses(
                                prevState => ({
                                    ...prevState,
                                    [key]: newStatus
                                })
                            )}
                        />
                    )
                })
            )}
        </>
    )
};
```

Comment: Everything works as you said, just that I am changing the state very often that's why I need the refs to not render the whole grid again and just re-render the node